# Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null. |||| cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

```
/E:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_firestore.dart:112:15: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
        Error.throwWithStackTrace(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/E:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:14:11: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
    Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/E:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:17:9: Error: Method not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
  Error.throwWithStackTrace(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/E:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.5.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:12:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
      ^
```

**import**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
```

**code**

```
void getData() async {
    CollectionReference userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("user");
  }
```

**pubspec.yaml**

environment:
sdk: ">=2.13.4 <3.0.0"

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^2.0.0
  firebase_core:
  firebase_messaging_platform_interface: ^3.1.1
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.1
  cloud_firestore_platform_interface: ^5.1.1
```

Comment: answer =>    from cloud_firestore: ^3.1.1    to   cloud_firestore: ^1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

from
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.1
to
cloud_firestore: ^1.0.1